# How to change vm name through pysphere

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyvmomi, pysphere

I'm using the Pysphere API written in python in order to manage VM operations.

My question is, how do I change the machine name after it was already cloned.

The API is [here](https://github.com/codekoala/pysphere) and [here](https://github.com/argos83/pysphere/blob/master/pysphere/vi_virtual_machine.py).

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, vm is already created/cloned. So basically you want to change the vm configuration.You need to create a configuration spec(vm name in your case).

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
print opArg
sI = connect.SmartConnect(host='',
             user='',
             pwd='',
             port=443,
             sslContext=context)
content = sI.content
objView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.VirtualMachine],True)
vmList = objView.view
for vm in vmList:
    vm_obj = vm
```

And then you pass your spec as-

```
vm_obj.ReconfigVM_Task(spec=your_spec)
```

I worked on VMWare a long time ago. I hope this is still helpful.